# how to get unique session Id from azure b2c sign-in

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am using azure b2c with web app integration with cookie based authentication. I am using standard sign-in user flow and i want to get unique session for every login so that i can tie up with customer journey and tracking for each login session.
Also I have observed that If i delete all the cookie from the web app still the customer is logged in even though the request doesn't have any cookie and on the server side I am getting all the claim of the customer. So how does this authorization flow work as there are no cookie and bearer token in the header

Comment: Do you mean you want to know which user login in? As far as I know, you could get the name from the user claims. Besides, if the request doesn't send the token to the server-sdie, the  authorization flow will not work. We need to know how you set the authentication and authorization in your web api. Please provide  the related codes.

Comment: I have set azure b-2c web app integration that follows the azure sample from the github. I'm getting username and all the properties that I set in my claim... but a customer can login multiple times a day so I need to some way to track the journey of customer from login to doing any activity and eventually logout... I mean in traditional asp.net Session Id is the unique property after authentication and we can use session Id to tie customer journey

Comment: As far as I know, in asp.net core the session ID is also stored  into the cookie and it contains a expire time. It is as same as the token. In my opinion, if you don't want that user login multiple time, the right way is extend the token expire time.

Comment: Is there a way to get session ID from the cookie as I can't see that in User claim. I don't know but scenario is customer login does his activity browse application then log off by clicking on sign-out. Then same customer can comeback and do a fresh login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to get session ID from the cookie as I can't see that in User claim.

If you want to get a session id in your application, you could refer to below codes:

Firstly, you should register the session in the startup.cs ConfigureServices method.

```
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    });
```

and add usesession method in the Configure method:

```
        app.UseSession();
```

Secondly, you could get the session id in controller:

```
        var re = HttpContext.Session.Id;
```

Notice: If you don't set any session in your controller, the sessionid will change for every request which sent from clinet side.

[image]

Comment: Will this session Id is going to be same  for entire session or it changes on every http request

Comment: This is as same as the token, if you don't set any data into session in the server side. The session id will change for every requests. If you set any daya into session in the server side. It will store the session id into the cookie and send it throuth the http request. This session ID will not changed. But it has the expire time which you could set in the options in startup.cs method.

Comment: Thanks , i implemented the changes but it seems like in my case HttpContext.Session.Id is changing on every http  request

Comment: Yes, you should set a session with value, then the sessionid will not change. Like this : ` HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeyName, "The Doctor");` Then the session id will not change for each request.